# For loop across multiple ggplot graphs

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have the following data and I am trying to construct a `for loop` across 3 stock symbols;

```
symbols <- c("HOG", "GE", "GOOG")
```

I have the following `ggplot`. I am trying to do two things.

1) Run a `ggplot` on all three of the symbols in `symbols`

2) Change the title of each `ggplot` to incorporate the correct symbols name

An example using `GOOG` below.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(subset(NFO_WCAnalysis, Ticker %in% c("GOOG"))) +
  geom_line(aes(Date, NFO, group = Ticker, colour = "Blue")) +
  geom_line(aes(Date, WC, group = Ticker, colour = "Red")) +
  labs(title="NFO and WC plot GOOG", x="Date", y="NFO / WC") +
  scale_color_manual(labels = c("NFO", "WC"), values = c("Blue", "Red")) +
  theme_bw() +
  guides(color=guide_legend("Legend"))
```

The data. (I can post my attempts at the `for loop` if necessary) I am also open to just using the base plot functionality instead of `ggplot`.

```
structure(list(Ticker = c("GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GOOG", "GE", 
"GE", "GE", "GE", "HOG", "HOG", "HOG", "HOG"), Date = c(2017, 
2016, 2015, 2014, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014, 2017, 2016, 2015, 2014
), REC = c(18705, 14232, 13909, 10849, 24438, 24076, 27022, 23237, 
2435.65, 2361.37, 2300.99, 2164.26), INV = c(749, 268, 0, 0, 
21923, 22354, 22515, 17689, 538.2, 499.92, 585.91, 448.87), OtherCurrentAssetsNotCash = c(80, 
596, 628, 852, 0, 0, 0, 0, 223.37, 227.06, 323.59, 370.96), Payables = c(3137, 
2041, 1931, 1715, 15153, 14435, 13680, 12067, 227.6, 235.32, 
235.61, 196.87), SpontaneousFunsIncDeftaxes = c(21476, 14941, 
14343, 13813, 19514, 18867, 17943, 14854, 529.82, 486.65, 471.97, 
449.32), NFO = c(-5079, -1886, -1737, -3827, 11694, 13128, 17914, 
14005, 2439.8, 2366.38, 2502.91, 2337.9), LTD = c(3969, 3935, 
1995, 3228, 110555, 105497, 147742, 190999, 4587.26, 4666.98, 
4832.47, 3761.53), EQ = c(152502, 139036, 120331, 103860, 64264, 
75827, 98273, 128158, 1844.28, 1920.16, 1839.65, 2909.29), OtherLongTermLiabilities = c(16211, 
7544, 5636, 4562, 144423, 119843, 165573, 238451, 382.97, 440.55, 
553.55, 468), FA = c(72987, 62089, 57347, 50531, 377945, 365183, 
493071, 654954, 6087.93, 6036.39, 5995.1, 5580.01), WC = c(99695, 
88426, 70615, 61119, -58703, -64016, -81483, -97346, 726.58, 
991.3, 1230.57, 1558.81), CreditPlusCashMinus = c(-104774, -90312, 
-72352, -64946, 70397, 77144, 99397, 111351, 1713.22, 1375.08, 
1272.34, 779.090000000001)), .Names = c("Ticker", "Date", "REC", 
"INV", "OtherCurrentAssetsNotCash", "Payables", "SpontaneousFunsIncDeftaxes", 
"NFO", "LTD", "EQ", "OtherLongTermLiabilities", "FA", "WC", "CreditPlusCashMinus"
), row.names = c(NA, -12L), class = "data.frame")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the best approach here is to create a list of `ggplot` objects, then just replace the text in what you currently have.

This is what I mean:

```
#This will store all our ggplot objects, not necessary, but this gives us some extra flexibility
plotList <- list()

#This will loop through each of the symbol names
for(symbol in symbols){

    #What you had before, but with minor changes
    plotList[[symbol]] <- ggplot(subset(NFO_WCAnalysis, Ticker %in% symbol)) +
      geom_line(aes(Date, NFO, group = Ticker, colour = "Blue")) +
      geom_line(aes(Date, WC, group = Ticker, colour = "Red")) +
      labs(title=paste0("NFO and WC plot ", symbol), x="Date", y="NFO / WC") +
      scale_color_manual(labels = c("NFO", "WC"), values = c("Blue", "Red")) +
      theme_bw() +
      guides(color=guide_legend("Legend"))

}
```

Notice all that is different in the plotting command is that the "GOOG" has been replaced with `symbol`, which is the object it loops through. In the title argument I've just used a `paste0` operation to concatenate what symbol name with the other text you want.

With objects stored in `plotList[[symbol]]` you can now call them however you want by using `plotList[["GOOG"]]` or whatever the name of the symbol you want is :)

Because it's a list, you can also use it sequentially, e.g. `plotList[[1]]`. This means you can loop through to print things too if you want to later, or just grab the ones you want.

e.g.

```
for(i in 1:3){

    print(plotList[[i]])

}
```

If you just want to plot things immediately in the first place, you can ditch the `plotList[[symbol]] <-` bit and just wrap all the `ggplot` instructions within a `print` command, and that will do the same job.

Good luck!

Comment: This should get more recognition, extremely helpful!

Comment: Hey! Thanks for the feedback. Super happy to see this is still helping people out. Good luck with your project :)

Answer (score 1):

Only a couple of changes are needed:

```
for(symbol in symbols)
  print(ggplot(subset(NFO_WCAnalysis, Ticker %in% symbol)) +
          geom_line(aes(Date, NFO, group = Ticker, colour = "Blue")) +
          geom_line(aes(Date, WC, group = Ticker, colour = "Red")) +
          labs(title= paste("NFO and WC plot", symbol), x = "Date", y = "NFO / WC") +
          scale_color_manual(labels = c("NFO", "WC"), values = c("Blue", "Red")) +
          theme_bw() +
          guides(color = guide_legend("Legend")))
```

Comment: Thanks! Certainly learned something new here! I was always starting loops off with `for(i in 1:length(symbols)){....` and running into many problems! Thanks again!

Comment: Shows how dynamic `ggplot` can be also, adding simply `symbol`in the `labs(title...` did not think it would be so clean!

Comment: @user113156, that's also a valid approach, in that case you could have written `symbols[i]` where I have `symbol`. But `for(symbol in symbols)` indeed looks somewhat nicer.

Answer (score 1):

I'd start by writing a function. I would also transform the data from wide-long format, which works better with ggplot:

```
library(tidyverse)

plotSymbol <- function(data, symbol) {
  data %>%
    filter(Ticker == symbol) %>%
    select(Date, NFO, WC) %>%
    gather(variable,value, -Date) %>%
    ggplot(aes(Date, value)) + 
      geom_line(aes(color = variable, group = variable)) +
      labs(title = paste("NFO and WC plot", symbol),
           y = "NFO, WC") +
      scale_color_manual(values = c("blue", "red")) +
      theme_bw()
}
```

Now you can run, for example:

```
plotSymbol(NFO_WCAnalysis, "GOOG")
```

And rather than a loop, you can use `lapply` to generate a list of `ggplot` objects, one per symbol:

```
plots <- lapply(symbols, function(x) plotSymbol(NFO_WCAnalysis, x))
```

Now you can do whatever you like with the list `plots`. With a few modifications to the code you could, for example, write to PNG files using the symbol as part of the file name.